# Android: Custom notification sound not playing

Tags: java, android, audio, notifications

I've tried pretty much all available answers on the site, but somehow I cannot get the notification sound to work. The current code I'm testing is this (the notification is built in an alarm reciever):

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity_.class), 0))
            .setContentText("temporary text")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/alert"))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

The sound however, can be played via MediaPlayer, so the format is not the issue here.
Could it have to do with the lenght of the sound (30 seconds)?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the sound format? I had problems with sounds that can be played via MediaPlayer, but not from notifications... try to replace your sound file by a wmv, for example. (I don't remember exactly the file format I had problems with)

Comment: I replaced with a wav, and tried removing the raw, not working.
Here's a little output, maybe you guys can figure something out if the path is wrong.
D/NotificationManager﹕ notify: notification.sound android.resource://*packagename( i have to hide it)*/raw/alert

Comment: for clarification: R.raw.sound means your sound file sits in res/raw/sound.jpg . And this sound can be reached as R.raw.sound from android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your .setSound() to this

```
.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                            + context.getPackageName() + "/"
                            + R.raw.alert))
```

Hope this will work

Comment: Tried mp3 and wma so far. Do I have to be more specific, I don't know much about codecs etc.

Comment: okay, if you think length of the sound can make the difference then try one with a smaller duration,if it works, then duration will be the issue and remember use the same code for .setSound() as i have posted.

Comment: Sorry I was away, but the shorter version also doesn't work. (5 seconds). Could that be too much?
So far I've eliminated the option that the URI is wrong because I'm using the same one for the media player and it's working.

Comment: Well I ended up using a player in my reciever, and set a deleteIntent to handle the stopping of the sound, but your answer helped me get the correct Uri, thank you.

Comment: @MukeshRana this code works but if device notification sound is off then it does not increase the volume and finally no notification sound listens

Comment: @user3233280 By device notification sound if off, you mean to say that if you uncheck that show notification checkbox in your settings/apps ??

Comment: no if user has set mobile phone notification sound mute then how can i sound my notification ?

Comment: lol How it can be possible. Have you ever played music on your phone by keeping mobile media sound off :P

Comment: After nearly 24hrs of hacking and searching this site without luck, this is the only answer that worked for me. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

**READ HERE** if the correct answer from Mukesh doesn't work for you!!

The answer published from Mukesh is correct, but for me it wasn't working until I discovered I configured the notification wrong!! (or there is an android BUG)

**This snippet doesn't work**

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( context )
     .setDefaults( DEFAULT_VIBRATE | FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS )
     .setContentTitle( title )
     .setContentText( message )

     .setSound( "android.resource://"
                        + context.getPackageName() + "/"
                        + R.raw.alert)).build();
```

-

**This snippet WORKS**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( context )
     .setContentTitle( title )
     .setContentText( message )
     .setSound( "android.resource://"
                        + context.getPackageName() + "/"
                        + R.raw.alert)).build();
```

-

```
.setDefaults( DEFAULT_VIBRATE | FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS )
```

*Observation:* Like you see the line above I doesn't use the constanst DEFAULT_SOUND, but still does't work.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! Was getting super frustrated that it wasn't playing my chosen sound, only the system notification sound.  Take the setDefaults off even if set to SOUND, and voila, works perfectly!

Comment: @Tano have you tried to play `Device stored file path URI` above `7.0  (N)` and `8.0 (O)` getting `FileUriExposedException` any idea about this

Comment: Thats all great but is there any limitation on the length of the notification sound?